# Is it a must for a dimension table to have a primary key?

Tags: data-warehouse

I have a question for you all. I searched first for any existing same question but only found related ones but not specific to my question. So here it goes:

Is it important that my dimension tables have a primary key? I am asking this because the way I designed my data warehouse is that I managed my surrogate keys on the Normalised Data Store. Then the surrogate key is just passed along to the dim tables. Any updates from the source systems will reflect first on the NDS (type 1 or override). So basically, I do not keep track of the historical values on the Normalised data store. However, I do keep track of the changes on the dimensional data store.

Because of this, the surrogate keys on the dim tables are not managed by the DB. If there are changes from the source system, a new row with the same surrogate key, same everything except the fields/columns for type 2 changes I selected.

Since there is no primary key on the dim tables, there will be no FK constraint on the fact tables. How will this affect the performance of the data warehouse when using the data mart (fact and dim tables with no PK/FK constraint)?

Here is a screenshot of my sample data:

http://i69.photobucket.com/albums/i47/boxingpics/dim_customer.jpg

Is this alright?

Comment: How will you join your dimension to a fact table without a key? I guess what you actually mean is that there is no *constraint* for the key. It's better to implement the constraint. Data integrity should always be enforced declaratively where possible. DBMS features like star-join optimisation and other optimisations depend on the existence of key constraints.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, I cannot create a primary key constraint on the dim tables due to the reasons I have highlighted above. A PK is unique right? If so, it is not possible to create one on the dim tables and with this, a FK constraint on the fact tables is not possible.

Comment: Its more usual to generate the surrogates in the star schema layer - many ETL tools manage the creation of surrogate keys and slowly changing dimensions automatically with no coding required.  If there is no primary key constraint on the dimensions, how do you know there are not duplicates being created, making the reporting inaccurate?

Comment: Your dimension tables should have their own surrogate keys. If you are tracking changes with a Type 2 dimension, then each of those rows gets its own key, even if the "natural" key is the same.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to have a primary key in your dimension table.

I'm guessing the NDS is simply using the surrogate key design pattern for managing entities across disparate source systems.  This isn't too uncommon...[here's](http://kejser.org/an-overview-of-source-key-pathologies/) a good post by Thomas Kejser covering a few of the issues that arise.

Bottom line, if your NDS is only tracking type-1 changes, and you need to track type-2 (historical) changes in the data mart, then you will need to add an additional surrogate key to the mix.